# Maven Jaxb Generated Package Names Are Backwards

Tags: maven, package, jaxb2

I have created a simple Maven project which uses Jaxb to compile a schema into Java files. Everything seems to be working but the problem is the generated package names are backwards:

[image: Windows Explorer]

My Xml schema looks like the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://com.mystuff.jaxb.inventorycontrol.inventorydata"
    targetNamespace="http://com.mystuff.jaxb.inventorycontrol.inventorydata" elementFormDefault="qualified" version="1.0.0">
    ....
    ....      
    <xs:complexType name="InventoryItemListType">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="Item" type="InventoryItemType" />
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>        
</xs:schema>
```

The namespace *http://com.mystuff.jaxb.inventorycontrol.inventorydata* starts with com and ends with inventorydata so I thought this would be the package/folder order:

```
com\mystuff\jaxb\inventorycontrol\inventorydata
```

but mine ends up backwards:

```
inventorydata\inventorycontrol\jaxb\mystuff\com\
```

Not sure if it's overkill to paste some of my pom.xml here but I guess it won't hurt.

Here is my root pom:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    ....
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <groupId>com.mystuff.jaxb</groupId>
    <artifactId>inventorycontrol</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    ....
    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                ....
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${maven-jaxb2-plugin-version}</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <catalog>src/main/resources/catalog.xml</catalog>
                        <catalogResolver>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2.resolver.tools.ClasspathCatalogResolver</catalogResolver>
                        <extension>true</extension>
                        <schemaDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/resources/xsd</schemaDirectory>
                        <schemaIncludes>
                            <include>*.xsd</include>
                        </schemaIncludes>
                    </configuration>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>generate</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>    
    </build>

    <modules>
        <module>inventorydata</module>
    </modules>

</project>
```

And here is the pom for the module that has the schema:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    ....
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.mystuff.jaxb</groupId>
        <artifactId>inventorycontrol</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.mystuff.jaxb.inventorycontrol</groupId>
    <artifactId>inventorydata</artifactId>
    ....
    <build>
        <plugins>
            ....
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

*_UPDATE_*

When I created my project I basically copy/pasted the schema/pom files from an old project to this new project. The old projects schema looked like the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://www.cmv.com/java/maven/jaxb/schemas/core/types"
    targetNamespace="http://www.cmv.com/java/maven/jaxb/schemas/core/types" elementFormDefault="qualified" version="1.0.0">
    ....
    <xs:complexType name="PoundsWeightType">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="Value" type="PositiveFloat" />
        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:attribute name="Units" type="UnitsEnum" use="required" fixed="Lbs" />
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

And my generated package for that project is:

```
com\cmv\java\maven\jaxb\schemas\core\types
```

[image: Project With Correct Order]

Which is what I would expect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Java components, packages, etc... are named using reverse dns. You're specifying the namespace in DNS format, meaning, well, that you're meant to reverse it.

The namespace `com.mystuff.jaxb.inventorycontrol.inventorydata`, written out as a url would be: `http://inventorydata.inventorycontrol.jaxb.mystuff.com`

Comment: I have another maven project that I copied the pom information from and it uses the same ordering for the namespace and the package names end up as I would expect, with com first. I made sure I didn't miss anything when I copied/modified the new pom files so I don't know why the behavior is different.

Comment: your poms look ok - you're using the DNS format in your xml schema.

Comment: Are you suggesting that my namespace in my schema be http://inventorydata.inventorycontrol.jaxb.mystuff.com? If so, that's backwards from 99% of all schemas I have seen. And, as I stated above, I am using the same ordering in my other project and all is good.

Comment: When you encode something as 64 bit encoding, it's going to look different then when you encode it as plain text. When you encode your schema name using reverse-DNS, you'll write it in one direction - and when you encode it using DNS, you'll write it in the other. Same schema, different format.

Comment: How do I change it to not use the DNS format as you suggest?

Comment: You're writing an XML schema, I don't think you have a choice in the matter. If it really bugs you, try not writing a url - ie, remove the http:// from the front. The real solution, though, is to stop editing xml files by hand. Editing xml by hand (besides giving you headaches like this) is a _really bad idea_

Comment: Okay well thank you for the information. I am going to respectfully not accept your answer. You are probably right and I am probably a bit too tired but I will wait and see. :) Note, I updated my original post        to show my other projects schema.

Comment: I am so dumb! I just realized that the reason why this is happening is because my namespace uses "."s rather than "/"s! http://com.mystuff.jaxb.inventorycontrol.inventorydata. I am going to go ahead and accept your answer. :) I told you I was tired!